# Django consistent custom log format

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to configure logging for Django so that I had session_key in every line of log (if set). I think I found a way:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'request': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(sessid)s] %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'request': {
            '()': 'yellowballs.yblogging.RequestFilter'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['request'],
            'formatter': 'request',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

With the filter being defined like that:

```
class RequestFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        session_store = SessionStore()
        record.sessid = session_store.session_key
        return True
```

It seems to work well, but Django's logging its messages with it's default format:

```
2013-03-01 08:44:41,359 WARNING  [None] Not Found: /
[01/Mar/2013 08:44:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1962
```

How do I get the lines `[01/Mar/2013 08:44:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1962` to display in the same format as the rest of the log?

Is there a simple and pretty way to override the default format for all Django so that the log messages would be consistent across the whole project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that those lines are logged not by my application but by `manage.py runserver` server. So there is no way of formatting them, instead logging the application logs into some files. That will remove those lines from application logs completely but that's okay since they don't belong there :)

Answer (score 2):

Override the default log format worked for me. It is **required** to stop the propagation.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        "verbose": {
            "format": (
                "%(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s [PID:%(process)d:%(threadName)s]"
            )
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False, ### NOTE HERE !!!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to use your formatter:

```
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'filters': ['set_sessid'],
        'formatter': 'request', // this
    },
},
```

Comment: yeah, now I've changed it and corrected the question but it doesn't solve the problem - Django's log messages are still in different format

Comment: try to change level for django logger to INFO or DEBUG. The log entries you see go through main 'django' logger and you have minimum ERROR level set

Comment: ok, changed it, but it doesn't help either; still getting those lines:
`[01/Mar/2013 02:41:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1962`